Failing EAP-TLS authentication on mobile phones with FreeRADIUS
I would like to automatically connect our iPhones to the network using a RADIUS server and EAP-TLS.
I use an MDM solution named Baramundi to deploy the configuration and the certificates to the devices.
The RADIUS server I am using is FreeRADIUS.
When watching the traffic between the authenticator and the RADIUS server by running the RADIUS server in debug mode, I see that the communication suddenly stops after four packets transmitted.
The last line I see in the RADIUS log is an Access-Challenge packet sent from the RADIUS server to the authenticator / supplicant and then, there's no packet sent anymore.
Obviously, the iPhone decides not do continue its conversation with the authenticator, but I have no clue, why.
Is there a way to debug that?
Are there log files I can check on the iPhone?
I realized, that the same phenomenon occurs with Android devices. Maybe it's easier to get the logs there?
Is there a step-by-step description on how to get that done? I guess, I'm just missing one tiny little bit, like some certificates OID missing on client side or on server side or so, but it's difficult to find out more without any error messages or logs...
Can anyone help?

Do you already have it working with wpa_supplicant on Linux, as that's more or less what Android uses anyway? (Or the eapol_test tool that directly speaks to RADIUS?)

I did not yet test using eapol_test. I did not know it. It is not part of FreeRADIUS, right? I'll check that tomorrow. This helps me find out if it's on the RADIUS end or if it's a Android/iOS issue and Giacomo is correct in that this is the wrong place to ask this question.

eapol_test is part of wpa_supplicant (the 'hostap' project) – often packaged separately in distributions. It therefore takes an EAP configuration similar to wpa_supplicant.conf, but tests directly against a RADIUS server. (If that works, the next step would be to use the actual wpa_supplicant to test a real connection against your AP, but still without Android/iOS in the mix.)

Are you saying your MDM system generates both the client cert and the matching private key and sends both to the client? Have you confirmed that the client is installing the private key (not just the client cert) that it got from the MDM? I find that most of the time people have problems with certificates, it's because they don't understand the role of the private keys and think that a cert alone is all that's needed.

I am deleting this question, as it turned out, that the WiFi AP was broken. With other APs, authentication is working perfectly fine.
